# Can not remove movie clip from stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm using as2 and coding from the main timeline, (using Flash Develop) because my teacher says I have to.

Here is the issue i am facing.

```
    _root.playBtn.onPress = function () 
    { 
        _root.gotoAndStop("level1");
        //picha = true;
        _root.attachMovie("picha", "player", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        _root.player._x = 300;
        _root.player._y = 200;


    }
```

when I press the play button, the movie clip is added and called "player".

```
    _root.hud.backBtn.onPress = function () 
    { 
        _root.gotoAndStop("start")
        _root.removeMovieClip(_root.player);
    }
```

But when I press the back button to go back to the menu, the player is not removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_root.player.removeMovieClip();
```

Comment: I have one more question, can  I ask here or will I have to make another question?

Comment: I think you can write it here (but I'm a neeby too here) :-)

Comment: _root.milk.gotoAndStop(Math.random() * 6); 

This should go to a frame inside that movie clip between one and six, but it doesn't..

Comment: Math.random() gives you a random number between 0 and 1 so with your script you can get 0.05 * 6 = 0.3 wich is not a frame.
`Math.round(1+(Math.random() * 5));` gives you an integer number from 1 to 6 (you get 0 to 5 as random number and than add 1 as minimum value).

Comment: Thank you again! Greatly explained! Thank you so much!